# Using const char* instead of const string

Tags: c++, stl, llvm

I was going through llvm source code and found the following function declaration.

```
int LLVMWriteBitcodeToFile(LLVMModuleRef M, const char *Path){...}
```

(at https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/lib/Bitcode/Writer/BitWriter.cpp)

Is there a reason to use **const char*** when we can instead use **const string**? Any performance-related reasons?

Comment: If you have a `const char*` and need to convert to a `string`, you incur a cost of object construction (which may include dynamic memory allocation). If you have a `string`, it's trivial to pass in the underlying `const char*` from `.c_str()`. Whatever this method calls may itself require a `const char*`, so there's no reason to pass in a `string`.

Comment: Modern code can benefit from `std::string_view`. It is safer than raw string pointers with zero runtime overhead; except for an initial `strlen` call on certain occasions. The interface is much like `std::string`.

Comment: In general using (STL) classes on interfaces comes with its own problems (ABI compatibility) and it is thus not recommended to export "C++ classes" on sdk's directly. That's why many API's still use (extern) "C" interfaces and only use integral types (and pointers to those types). This is also a lesson for you, never export classes and their member variables which could be (STL) classes too directly. Use extern "C" and/or use the pimpl pattern on your own sdk's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally in projects with shared C and C++ code, in libraries which are used from other languages and sometimes also between pure C++ projects, people refrain from using non-trivial C++ classes (especially ones that allocate memory such as `std::string`) on interface boundaries.

This **a)** allows easy C-bindings and **b)** prevents ABI-incompatibility issues, e.g. when the caller is using a different standard library version or a different `malloc` implementation than what the called function was compiled with.

In the case of LLVM the reason is probably that they want to enable C code to call their interfaces.

Here you can find the C-header declaring the function in question:
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/include/llvm-c/BitWriter.h